# why is discrete random variable defined on counting measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$$E(\phi(X))=\int\phi Pdv_s=\sum_x\phi(x)P(x)$$ where $V_s$ is counting measure. It looks unnatural to me that we define expectation on counting measure even though counting measure never sums up to 1? How to understand this intuitively? Is this actually dirac delta function?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function

Comment: What is $\phi$, what is $X$ and what is $P$?

Comment: a function, a random variable, measure w.r.t. x

Comment: The probability measure lurking in the background here is not $\nu_s$, indeed, but the measure $(P\nu_s)$ defined by $$(P\nu_s)(B)=\sum_{x\in B}P(x)$$ All this is a rather convoluted way of saying that, for every $x$, $$\Pr(X=x)=P(x)$$